# I want to Create JSON schema with java code

Tags: java, json

I am using Json type for my data, and i need a json schema to make a better description.
Can a sample Java code provide json schema?
I want a sample example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally data model ( Java POJOs ) for the JSON is shared between data transferring parties. 
But if you really want, then "jackson" can be used, example below converts a Java class to JSON Schema. You can furthe play around or look for similar libraries, tio suit your requirement.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchemaGenerator;


 private String getJsonSchema(Class clazz) throws IOException
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGen = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
        com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema schema = schemaGen.generateSchema(clazz);
        return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema);
    }
```